# Not all the received data is being stored into the variable

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving serial data and trying to save it into a variable, using a start and stop symbol ("{" and "}" respectively). The data is typically received in two parts, and the first part (with the "{" code) is not being saved into the variable but the second part is.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

    Dim portData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
    Console.WriteLine(portData & "@")
    For i As Integer = 0 To (portData.Length - 1)
        If (portData.Substring(i, 1) = "}" And (DotFound = True)) Then ' end
            DotFound = False
            txtRx.Text += dataRxd & "*" & vbLf
            dataRxd = ""

        ElseIf (portData.Substring(i, 1) = "{" And (DotFound = False)) Then ' begin
            DotFound = True
            dataRxd = dataRxd + portData.Substring(i, 1)
        End If

        If (DotFound = True) Then
            dataRxd = dataRxd + portData.Substring(i, 1)
        End If

    Next
```

The output console indicates that all data is being sent, and the code registers the start and stop symbols.

(Sample data:

Output window: 
{FF2D035482@
08027915807487@

Text window: 
08027915807487*)

'DotFound' is set up as a global variable.

Comment: What is your input example that gives the output example you have shown?

Comment: This is what is being received: {FF2D03548208027915807487}

Comment: Don't concatenate the strings with "+", rather use the ampersand "&". For some reason, you've even mixed the two in one line.